# Laravel-Excel toArray validation not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using the laravel-excel package and want to import excel into an array, it works well for the main code (without validation), but when I tried to add validation/rule, the validation not working properly (I mean, like the validation is just skipped, so if I upload a file that doesn't fit the format, the array output still comes out), here's my import code

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Request;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class RequestImport implements ToModel, WithValidation, WithHeadingRow
{
    use Importable;

    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Request([
            'no' => $row[0],
            'username' => $row[1],
            'name' => $row[2],
        ]);
    }

    // create validation by heading row
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'no' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

and here's my controller code when I call the RequestImport class

```
$file = request()->file('fileExcel');

// save file
if (isset($request->upload)) {
    $this->saveFile($file);
}

// return excel import into array
$data = (new RequestImport)->toArray($file); //here I call the RequestImport

return response()->json([
    'status' => 'success',
    'message' => 'success,
    'data' => $data[0],
]);
```

Is something wrong with my code? or I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

it's not official but I found a workaround.
first, I added importable concern,
then defined a class attribute $data.
this will store rows once all validations are satisfied.

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class ImportData implements ToArray, WithValidation, WithHeadingRow
{
    use Importable;
    public $data;

    public function array(array $rows)
    {
        $this->data = $rows;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            // validation rules
        ];
    }
}
```

in my controller

```
$import = new ImportData;
Excel::import($import, request()->file('file'));
return response()->json($import->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You try changing the key to index

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Request([
        'no' => $row[0],
        'username' => $row[1],
        'name' => $row[2],
    ]);
}

// create validation by heading row
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        '0' => 'required',
        '1' => 'required',
        '2' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

more info read in [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html)